# Resctrict folders for sftp when using ssh version < 4.0

Tags: ssh, sftp

We have a very old server (it's kind of embarrassing to write the OS version), but this is the situation, and **upgrade OS or ssh is not an option** for some reasons.
`uname -a > FreeBSD xxx 4.11-STABLE FreeBSD 4.11-STABLE`

The problem is that some customer should upload files on a daily basis using sftp, and as far as I know we can't restrict folders using the directive `ChrootDirectory` due to the old version of ssh:
`OpenSSH_3.5p1 FreeBSD-20030924, SSH protocols 1.5/2.0`

I have found some alternatives when googling, but most of them includes patching openssh, or installing some other program. We can't install e.g. `pureftpd` because of the "old" server.

**The question:**
Is there a way of restricting folders when using `OpenSSH_3.5p1`, or some other alternative that is easy to install on this server?
I repeat: **upgrade OS or ssh is not an option** for various reasons.
The situation with the server is that we can't risk that ssh isn't working when restarting, ssh is the only way for us to reach that.

I think it's kind of strange that I couldn't find any "easy" solution to this, there must have been many other that wants to restrict folders, also back in the days when our server was up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could always make a chroot and run sshd inside the chroot, instead of having sshd chroot itself.

In order to do that, you create a separate file system hierarchy, e.g. `/chroot/`, that contains only the binaries needed to allow login and the libraries those binaries need in order to be executed. You'll also create a passwd, shadow and group file containing the sshd user and so on. You'll probably want to have a separate IP for this user's sshd, or else run it on a separate port.

There's a basic tutorial at [adminarticles.com](http://www.adminarticles.com/create-a-simple-chroot-jail/) about creating a simple chroot.

Since you're running FreeBSD, another option is to use the built-in `jail` system. I believe the man page will give you all the information you need to set one up - it's basically a chrooted system with some extra bells and whistles, similar to the Solaris zones.

Comment: Thanks, can you explain that more? I will be happy with a link

Comment: I've added some further information.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in right direction, I'm a total newbie on this so I didn't even know what to google on. I found some links on `chroot jail ftp` after reading your answer, and it turned out that this was already set up on the server, but someone had changed the login shell from `/sbin/nologin` to some login shell, so the "ftp customer" was able to login as a "normal" user :( Don't know if I should add some information if some newbie like me stumble in to this thread, when I first googled I found a lot of questions like mine, without a good answer. Thanks again.